# Array data parse to generate HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array of data from which i would need to generate a html table,
for instance if day `=` Saturday, it should be go under the column Saturday. I have attached a picture of the expected output. Could someone please suggest or give an idea as to how to achieve this?

**Array data :**

"[{"start":"20170211T123000","end":"20170211T133000","summary":"SA meeting1","day":"SA"
"start":"20170106T170000","end":"20170106T173000","summary":"friday meeting1","day":"FR"
"start":"20170106T180000","end":"20170106T183000","summary":"friday meeting2","day":"FR"
"start":"20160614T190000","end":"20160614T194500","summary":"Thur meeting2","day":"TH"
"start":"20160614T190000","end":"20160614T194500","summary":"Thur meeting4","day":"TH"
"start":"20160620T160000","end":"20160620T164500","summary":"wed meeting1","day":"WE"
"start":"20160610T160000","end":"20160610T163000","summary":"friday meetin3","day":"FR"
"start":"20160614T164500","end":"20160614T173000","summary":"Thur meeting3","day":"TH"
"start":"20160620T181500","end":"20160620T190000","summary":"wed meeting3","day":"WE"
"start":"20160620T181500","end":"20160620T190000","summary":"Muay Thai Kickboxing","day":"WE"
"start":"20160618T090000","end":"20160618T094500","summary":"SA meeting 3","day":"SA"
"start":"20160618T094500","end":"20160618T103000","summary":"SA meeting 2","day":"SA"
"start":"20160613T190000","end":"20160613T194500","summary":"Monday meeting2,"day":"MO"
"start":"20160613T190000","end":"20160613T194500","summary":"Monday meeting1","day":"MO"
"start":"20160613T173000","end":"20160613T181500","summary":"tues meeting2","day":"TU"
"start":"20160613T173000","end":"20160613T181500","summary":"tues meeting 3","day":"TU"}]"

Html table as shown in the picture.

[HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRqaX.png)

Comment: Is that a one object array?

Comment: yes.. thats Right Johan...

Comment: man your data are wrong.

Comment: oops... i think to correct ....https://snag.gy/oPV720.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create HTML table from JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684201/create-html-table-from-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one ugly way of doing it.

You first need to sort your data in such a way that you can actually use it.

Let's create an object `dict` such that each property is the day and its corresponding value is an array of the related items.

And then use it to build your table.

```js
var items = [{
  "start": "20170211T123000",
  "end": "20170211T133000",
  "summary": "SA meeting1",
  "day": "SA"
}, {
  "start": "20170106T170000",
  "end": "20170106T173000",
  "summary": "friday meeting1",
  "day": "FR"
}, {
  "start": "20170106T180000",
  "end": "20170106T183000",
  "summary": "friday meeting2",
  "day": "FR"
}, {
  "start": "20160614T190000",
  "end": "20160614T194500",
  "summary": "Thur meeting2",
  "day": "TH"
}, {
  "start": "20160614T190000",
  "end": "20160614T194500",
  "summary": "Thur meeting4",
  "day": "TH"
}, {
  "start": "20160620T160000",
  "end": "20160620T164500",
  "summary": "wed meeting1",
  "day": "WE"
}, {
  "start": "20160610T160000",
  "end": "20160610T163000",
  "summary": "friday meetin3",
  "day": "FR"
}, {
  "start": "20160614T164500",
  "end": "20160614T173000",
  "summary": "Thur meeting3",
  "day": "TH"
}, {
  "start": "20160620T181500",
  "end": "20160620T190000",
  "summary": "wed meeting3",
  "day": "WE"
}, {
  "start": "20160620T181500",
  "end": "20160620T190000",
  "summary": "Muay Thai Kickboxing",
  "day": "WE"
}, {
  "start": "20160618T090000",
  "end": "20160618T094500",
  "summary": "SA meeting 3",
  "day": "SA"
}, {
  "start": "20160618T094500",
  "end": "20160618T103000",
  "summary": "SA meeting 2",
  "day": "SA"
}, {
  "start": "20160613T190000",
  "end": "20160613T194500",
  "summary": "Monday meeting2",
  "day": "MO"
}, {
  "start": "20160613T190000",
  "end": "20160613T194500",
  "summary": "Monday meeting1",
  "day": "MO"
}, {
  "start": "20160613T173000",
  "end": "20160613T181500",
  "summary": "tues meeting2",
  "day": "TU"
}, {
  "start": "20160613T173000",
  "end": "20160613T181500",
  "summary": "tues meeting 3",
  "day": "TU"
}];

var dict = {
  'MO': [],
  'TU': [],
  'WE': [],
  'TH': [],
  'FR': [],
  'SA': []
};

// EDIT/TODO: probably want to sort your items here by date before sorting them into the dictionary

// sort the data
items.forEach(function(item) {
   if (dict.hasOwnProperty(item.day)) {
       dict[item.day].push(item);
   } 
});

// get maximum number of rows
var rows = Math.max(...[dict.MO.length, dict.TU.length, dict.WE.length, dict.TH.length, dict.FR.length, dict.SA.length]);

// print the table
var html = '<table>';

// create table header
html += '<tr>';
['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'].forEach(function(day) {
  html += '<th>' + day + '</th>';
});
html += '</tr>';

// create table body
html += '<tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  html += '<tr>';
  ['MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA'].forEach(function(day, j) {
    var info = dict[day][i];
    html += '<td>' + (info ? info.summary : '') + '</td>';
  });
  html += '</tr>';
}
html += '</tr>';

html += '</table>';

// put generated HTML into container
output.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!-- container to hold table -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

For information regarding the use of `Max.max()` and spread operator i.e. `...`, look at the [last example on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

**Edit**

It seems the data is not fully sorted as in your example -- which means you will need to fix the sorting logic some more -- but this answer gives you enough to move forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help for a simpler solution.... can  i ask you one question please? How can i ignore a array if the day=SU?  I thought the belwo code by itseld will skip if the day is not the given list,.... please advise...                 ['MO', 'TU', 'WE', 'TH', 'FR', 'SA'].forEach(function(day, j)

Comment: The dictionary does not include Sunday, so when you add the items to the dictionary, you can simply check if the day is in the dictionary. Check last edit.

Comment: Got it...ok great it works..! one last question...I am update the style in html instead of css..and update the changes in this fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/Thea123/csgksg6g/ any idea what am missing here.. the <td> style is not working :(

Comment: You should mark the answer as answered then. Maybe missing single quote `'` (line 119) ? If not, then you should ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it - check the jsfiddle at the bottom to run it...

```
<table id="week" style="border-collapse: collapse;"> 
</table>
<script>

var headings = {
MO: "Monday",
TU: "Tuesday",
WE: "Wednesday",
TH: "Thursday",
FR: "Friday",
SA: "Saturday"
};

var daylist = [];
var daycnt = [];

var obj = [
{start:"20170211T123000",end:"20170211T133000",summary:"SA meeting1",day:"SA"},
{start:"20170106T170000",end:"20170106T173000",summary:"friday meeting1",day:"FR"},
{start:"20170106T180000",end:"20170106T183000",summary:"friday meeting2",day:"FR"},
{start:"20160614T190000",end:"20160614T194500",summary:"Thur meeting2",day:"TH"},
{start:"20160614T190000",end:"20160614T194500",summary:"Thur meeting4",day:"TH"},
{start:"20160620T160000",end:"20160620T164500",summary:"wed meeting1",day:"WE"},
{start:"20160610T160000",end:"20160610T163000",summary:"friday meetin3",day:"FR"},
{start:"20160614T164500",end:"20160614T173000",summary:"Thur meeting3",day:"TH"},
{start:"20160620T181500",end:"20160620T190000",summary:"wed meeting3",day:"WE"},
{start:"20160620T181500",end:"20160620T190000",summary:"Muay Thai Kickboxing",day:"WE"},
{start:"20160618T090000",end:"20160618T094500",summary:"SA meeting 3",day:"SA"},
{start:"20160618T094500",end:"20160618T103000",summary:"SA meeting 2",day:"SA"},
{start:"20160613T190000",end:"20160613T194500",summary:"Monday meeting2",day:"MO"},
{start:"20160613T190000",end:"20160613T194500",summary:"Monday meeting1",day:"MO"},
{start:"20160613T173000",end:"20160613T181500",summary:"tues meeting2",day:"TU"},
{start:"20160613T173000",end:"20160613T181500",summary:"tues meeting 3",day:"TU"}];


// start by sorting the data into time order
function compare(a,b) {
  if(a.start < b.start)
    return -1;
  if (a.start > b.start)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
obj.sort(compare);

// first, setup the headers
var insert = "<tr>";
Object.keys(headings).forEach(function(key) {
  insert += "<th style='border:1px solid #000'>" + headings[key] + "</th>";
  daycnt[key] = 0;
  daylist[key] = {};
});

// now build up an array for each day of the week
var maxcnt = 0;
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++) {
  var day = obj[i].day;
  var index = daycnt[day];
  daylist[day][index] = obj[i].summary;
  daycnt[day] = daycnt[day] + 1;
  if(daycnt[day] > maxcnt) maxcnt = daycnt[day];
}

// now fill the table columns
for(var i=0; i<maxcnt; i++) {
  insert += "<tr>";
  Object.keys(headings).forEach(function(key) {
    if(daycnt[key]<=i)
      insert += "<td style='border:1px solid #000;padding:4px;'></td>";
    else
      insert += "<td style='border:1px solid #000;padding:4px;'>" + daylist[key][i] + "</td>";
  });
  insert += "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById("week").innerHTML = insert;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/FrancisMacDougall/sr6zfpbo/

Comment: Hi... Thank u so much...It helps a lot..!! Appreciated