# IBM IoTF subscribe to event

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I am able to get the events from IBM IoTF to my Node Js application. Now how do I show in html table?

```
appClient.on("deviceEvent", function (deviceType, deviceId, eventType, format, payload) {
    var json_string = JSON.parse(payload);
    console.log(json_string);    
});
```

Comment: This question is similar to [Create Html Table From Javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684201/create-html-table-from-javascript-object).

Comment: It doesn't work. This is Node Js server end, I want to send the data to the front end

Comment: Im not sure about what exactly you are looking to do?

Comment: I found something similar to what you been describing about getting events from IBm IOTF. Do look at the following link. The have detailed steps on building an iot app in nodjs. Look for the heading 'Build a Node.js web application using ibmiotf library'.
Are you using this same link to build you IOT app?

https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/build-an-iot-bluemix-app-in-node-js-with-sensors-on-raspberry-pi/