# Fill html table with js data in svelte

Tags: svelte

I'm following the tutorial in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmdOZ5NSqb8 and I copied everything like him in my svelte project to try, but for some reason as a result I get a blank page when I run the code. If I comment out the  part I see the header of the table though.
In the console of the web page I get this : "Uncaught TypeError: table is null". Is it because I did something wrong or because it works different with svelte ? I read through this as well : [Create HTML table from JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684201/create-html-table-from-javascript-object) but it seems to me that it is saying the same thing as the video tutorial.

I'm not sure if I've been trying to find a solution for too long and I don't see the obvious or if it is something new to me, anyway thank you for your help. Here is the code if you want to try it

Cheers

```
<script>
var myArray = [
        {"name":"Bob", "age":"30", "birthday":"11/10/1990"},
        {"name":"Dan", "age":"40", "birthday":"11/10/1980"},
        {"name":"Thierry", "age":"50", "birthday":"11/10/1970"},
        {"name":"Patrick", "age":"60", "birthday":"11/10/1960"},
    ]


buildTable(myArray)

function buildTable(data){
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable")

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var row = `<tr>
                        <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].age}</td>
                        <td>${data[i].birthday}</td>
                  </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}

</script>

<table class="content-table buyside">
    <tr>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Your code is not really a svelte component, but a normal javascript program. Below is the Svelte version of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App.svelte

```
<script>
    const myArray = [
        {"name":"Bob", "age":"30", "birthday":"11/10/1990"},
        {"name":"Dan", "age":"40", "birthday":"11/10/1980"},
        {"name":"Thierry", "age":"50", "birthday":"11/10/1970"},
        {"name":"Patrick", "age":"60", "birthday":"11/10/1960"},
     ]
</script>

<table class="content-table buyside">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Birthday</th>
  </tr>
  {#each myArray as data}
     <tr>
        <td>{data.name}</td>
        <td>{data.age}</td>
        <td>{data.birthday}</td>
      </tr>`
  {/each}
</table>
```