# HTML table not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, object, html-table

I wanted to display a javascript object variable as a HTML table when a button with the id "stop" is pressed. I took some of my code for this problem from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684201/create-html-table-from-javascript-object), however for some reason the browser doesn't even render the table.

Html

```
<table id="tbody"></table>
```

JavaScript

```js
stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.style.display = "none";
  stop.style.display = "none";
  tbody.style.display = "block";


  ratings = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ratings);
  for (let i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
      let tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>" + ratings[i].key.toString() + "</td>" + "<td>" + ratings[i].value.toString() + "</td></tr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
  }
});
```

I even specifically mention the display in my javascript file, as you can see:

```js
 tbody.style.display = "block";
```

If needed, you can find the full code [here](https://github.com/AviralDhingra/car_rating/tree/main)

Comment: How are you saying to `sessionStorage`?

Comment: sessionStorage.ratings is an object I had applied "JSON.stringify" to previously in my code hence the parsing to make it an object again. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I pasted part of your code (https://jsfiddle.net/w0L62nz4/) and it seems working well. There is any message in your browser's console?

Comment: Nope, no error. It just doesn't display the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashish Kumar was right, the rating variable was an object. The TypeError (that came later) occurred because I was indexing the object like an array. Fixed that through the following edit in the event listener function :

```js
stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.style.display = "none";
  stop.style.display = "none";
  tbody.style.display = "block";

  ratings = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ratings);
  // console.log(ratings);
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(ratings).length; i++) {
      let tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>" + Object.keys(ratings)[i] + "</td>" + "<td>" + Object.values(ratings)[i] + "</td></tr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
stop.addEventListener("click", () => {
  container.style.display = "none";
  stop.style.display = "none";

  ratings = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.ratings); // RATINGS IS OBJECT HERE
  for (let i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) { // ratings.length will not work as it's not an array
      let tr = "<tr>";

      /* Verification to add the last decimal 0 */
      if (ratings[i].value.toString().substring(ratings[i].value.toString().indexOf('.'), ratings[i].value.toString().length) < 2) 
          ratings[i].value += "0";

      /* Must not forget the $ sign */
      tr += "<td>" + ratings[i].key.toString() + "</td>" + "<td>" + ratings[i].value.toString() + "</td></tr>";

      /* We add the table row to the table body */
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
  }
});
```

Please see the comments added at line 4 and 5

Comment: Why are you assuming ratings is not an array?

Comment: You are right, sessionStorage.Ratings is an object however the table doesn't show up even if I change the for loop to this :
```for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(ratings).length; i++) ``` There seems to be a TypeError

Comment: @DanielBeck because I executed the program Sir.